# Did Queen Vashti have a child?

Tags: midrash, purim, megillat-esther, tractate-megillah

Usually, the reason for Queen Vashti's punishment (leprosy or the growth of a tail) is related to the prophecy about the extinction of the Babylonian royal line.

Rav said: “*Everything God promised [to do to Babylon] happened through him (=Ahasuerus). For it is written (Isa. 14:22): ‘and I will cut off from Babylon name and remnant, kith and kin.’ ‘Name’ is Nebuchadnezzar. ‘Remnant’ is Awil-Marduk. ‘Kith’ is Belshazzar. ‘Kin’ is Vashti.*”

In fact, after the angel Gabriel gave her leprosy and/or made her grow a tail, clearly no one would ever make love to her again and, even if she wasn't executed, she could no longer make a Babylonian Royal Baby.

But I found in Ginzberg a mention to a child she had before:

[Vashti] *fairly revelled in the opportunity his command gave her to indulge in carnal pleasures once again, for it was exactly a week **since she had been delivered of a child***.
(Ginzberg, Legends of the Jews 4:12)

Has anyone ever heard of this child?

Comment: I heard that she had a son. Not sure of a source though or if it's reliable.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ian and thanks for this first well-phrased question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

The only such reference I know is *Tafsir Megillat Ester* ("Interpretation of the Book of Esther") by Shahin, a Persian Jewish poet of the 14th century, who talks about love between Shiruyeh, son of Vashti, and Mahzād, a Chinese princess.  I believe it is fictional.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that.